# Show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sqrt[n]{(3n+10)^{10}}} {2n} = 0$

Tags: limits

By just looking at it I'd say that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sqrt[n]{(3n+10)^{10}}} {2n}$ is $0$. However I do not know a way to show that. I kind of feel like there is a rule I don't know. A hint would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

[Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) is your friend.  For sufficiently large $n$, we have:

$$0 < \frac{ \sqrt[n]{(3n+10)^{10}}}{2n} < \frac{ \sqrt[n]{(3n+10)^{n/2}}}{2n} = \frac{\sqrt{3n+10}}{2n}$$

There are a number of ways to approach calculating $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \sqrt{3n+10}}{2n}$.  For instance, this is an indeterminant form....

Answer (score 2):

$$0 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{(3n+10)^{10}}}{n}\leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{(4n)^{10}}}{n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \frac{((4n)^{\frac1n })^{10}}{n} =0$$

Note that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 4^{\frac1n}=1$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac1n}=1$